# How to hide a specific user profile?

Tags: 8, users

I would like to be able to hide a specific user profile.

I want to completely hide it from Drupal and search engines. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the page from Google and search engines, you can add the `robots` metatag.

Add this code to a custom module to add the metatag to the specefic profile page.

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $user_id = 'ID of the user to hide profile page for';

  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.user.canonical') {
    $user = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('user');
    if ($user instanceof \Drupal\user\UserInterface && $user->id() == $user_id) {
      $robots_none = [
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => [
          'name' => 'robots',
          'content' => 'none',
        ],
      ];

      $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$robots_none, 'robots-none'];
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to hide the page in Drupal too, you can create a redirect from the specific user profile page to the `/system/403` page.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to completely hide the page itself. How would I do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer, `If you want to hide the page in Drupal too, you can create a redirect from that page to the 403 page using the redirect module.`

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped.

Comment: I have set the robots.txt with the metatag module

Answer (score 3):

To avoid users can access a user profile, I would implement [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/8.8.x).
For the search engines, it would be sufficient to check the logged-in user isn't anonymous. For any Drupal user and the search engines, it's sufficient to check the permission the logged-in user has. (I would not hide the user profile to users who have the permission to administer users.)

In the first case, I would use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_user_access(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
  if ($operation == 'view' && $entity->id() == USER_ID && $account->isAnonymous()) {
    return AccessResult::forbidden()->cachePerUser();
  }
}
```

In the second case, I would use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_user_access(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
  if ($operation == 'view' && $entity->id() == USER_ID && !$account->hasPermission('administer users')) {
    return AccessResult::forbidden()->cachePerPermissions();
  }
}
```

(In both the cases, replace `USER_ID` with the actual user ID of the user profile you need to hide.)

The code checks the value of the operation, and forbids it only when it's *view*. In this way, the code is simpler, as it doesn't need to check users are trying to edit their own accounts, for example (which I assume it's not an operation you want to forbid).

`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()` is not invoked for pages listing more than one entity, for example a view page. In the case of user accounts, `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()` should be sufficient, but if you want to avoid that user account is listed also in a view output, the alternative is [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/8.8.x) which is more complicated to implement, but it works in every case.